# Formatting a number with commas and cents while typing in textbox

Tags: vb.net

Pro devs, I want to ask questions on you. I expect you could help me. My question is: I have a Textbox named "txtUnitPrice" what I need is when I type a number on it it will auto-generate the commas and decimals of that number, example: when I type a number "4" it will display "4.00" and when I type "1000" it will display "1,000.00" how can I do that, please help me.

I tried many questions here that are related to my problem but none of them can help me.

Here's my code:

```
Private Sub txtUnitPrice_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtUnitPrice.TextChanged
    Dim input As Double = Double.Parse(txtUnitPrice.Text)
    Dim inputNumWithCommas As String = input.ToString("N0", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    txtUnitPrice.Text = inputNumWithCommas
End Sub
```

The code above is not my desired output. Please help me thanks.

Comment: I strongly recommend against that.  I would suggest that you just let the user type the number as they want and then handle the `Validating` and `Validated` events. The first event would be used to ensure that the input is a valid number and the second event would be used to format that number.  I would suggest also handling the `Enter` event and removing the formatting there.

Comment: I respect your answer sir, but I want to know how to do that, that is my objective why I asked a question. thank you, sir, for your recommendation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now a easy way would be to add a button under the textbox and then use this for when the button is pressed and after you input a number to `txtUnitPrice`

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        txtUnitPrice.Text = FormatCurrency(txtUnitPrice.Text)
End Sub
```

Another way which will update in real time without the need of a button would be something similar to this

```
Dim strCurrency As String = ""
Dim acceptableKey As Boolean = False

Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles txtUnitPrice.KeyDown
        If (e.KeyCode >= Keys.D0 And e.KeyCode <= Keys.D9) OrElse (e.KeyCode >= Keys.NumPad0 And e.KeyCode <= Keys.NumPad9) OrElse e.KeyCode = Keys.Back Then
            acceptableKey = True
        Else
            acceptableKey = False
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtUnitPrice.KeyPress
        ' Check for the flag being set in the KeyDown event.
        If acceptableKey = False Then
            ' Stop the character from being entered into the control since it is non-numerical.
            e.Handled = True
            Return
        Else
            If e.KeyChar = Convert.ToChar(Keys.Back) Then
                If strCurrency.Length > 0 Then
                    strCurrency = strCurrency.Substring(0, strCurrency.Length - 1)
                End If
            Else
                strCurrency = strCurrency & e.KeyChar
            End If

            If strCurrency.Length = 0 Then
                txtUnitPrice.Text = ""
            ElseIf strCurrency.Length = 1 Then
                txtUnitPrice.Text = "0.0" & strCurrency
            ElseIf strCurrency.Length = 2 Then
                txtUnitPrice.Text = "0." & strCurrency
            ElseIf strCurrency.Length > 2 Then
                txtUnitPrice.Text = strCurrency.Substring(0, strCurrency.Length - 2) & "." & strCurrency.Substring(strCurrency.Length - 2)
            End If
            txtUnitPrice.Select(TextBox1.Text.Length, 0)

        End If
e.Handled = True
    End Sub
```

May want to change a few things but ill leave that up to you to play with.

Comment: thanks, K.Madden, I will try this one, and I will update you soon.

Comment: No problem! Let me know how you get on.

Comment: thank you for helping me Sir/Ma'am. God bless. It's working.

Comment: K.Madden I have a new problem can you help me?

Comment: I can try! what is it?

Comment: K.Madden, the commas in the number when the digits are in the thousands. example: 1,000.00 Just like that thank you. :)

Comment: I'm not sure myself, but an idea would be to look at the bit where it says ` ElseIf strCurrency.Length > 2 Then` and so on. How many numbers in a thousand? 4 so I would suggest playing around with something like
` ElseIf strCurrency.Length > 4 Then...` write code similar to above to add a "," comma in. Understand?

Comment: So what you want it to do would even add another elseif into the above and have something like `ElseIf strCurrency.Length > 4 Then txtUnitPrice.Text = strCurrency.Substring(0, 1)& ","&strCurrency.Substring(1, strCurrency.Length - 3 ) & "." & strCurrency.Substring(strCurrency.Length - 2) `

Comment: hehe Right. Actually, I look on that but the logic behind I get stuck on that.

Comment: Thanks K.Madden I try that one. thank you God bless.

Comment: K.madden there is a problem again. when I type a 100 digit the output is "1,00.00" I tried to edit the code but I don't get it.

Comment: @MarkNartea you need to try learn the code for yourself! Think about it, its one digit short of 1000 so perhaps make a change to the code i supplied, play around with it! I helped all I can I can do the program for you! try this if you must `ElseIf strCurrency.Length > 4 Then txtUnitPrice.Text = strCurrency.Substring(0, 1)& ","&strCurrency.Substring(1, strCurrency.Length - 2 ) & "." & strCurrency.Substring(strCurrency.Length - 2)` i just changed one number.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195509/discussion-between-k-madden-and-mark-nartea).